# How to implement the call back mechanism between Activites

Tags: android, android-intent, android-event

I have 2 activities first details activity and second activity page is confirmationPage,Once i confirm it should come back to first page,how should i handle this scenario?

Is it possible between activities,instead of using fragments?

Comment: use `startActivityForResult();` to send response from your child `Activity` to it's parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use startActivityForResult(); method when you start the secondActivity.

and you also have to implement the onActivityResult() method.

Here is the code for first Activity..

```kotlin
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 1) {
            Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
            String ID = extra.getString("NameKey").trim();
             // do your code here.
            
        }
    }
```

Code in the second Activity..

add the code on confirm click button.

```kotlin
  Intent i = new Intent();
  Bundle extra = new Bundle();
  extra.putString("NameKey", KeyValue);
                
  i.putExtras(extra);
  setResult(1, i);
  finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

Start confirmationPage for result by `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`,

Here is a complete example (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/#usingintents_sub)

Answer (score 1):

I believe calling finish() is the easiest way to back out of an activity. It should return to the previous one similar to if you hit the back button.

edit: Although, as Sirlate mentioned, startActivityForResult is probably your best bet if you wish to return data.